# WordPress jQuery not enqueueing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to enqueue my jQuery files but it still doesn't work. In my `assets/functions.js` I have the following debugging code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.jQuery) {  
        // jQuery is loaded  
        alert("yup");
    } else {
        // jQuery is not loaded
        alert("derp");
    }
}
```

I am calling this file with this script, located at the top of the file:

```
if ( ! defined( 'TS_FILE' ) ) { define( 'TS_FILE', __FILE__ ); }

function ts_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    wp_register_script( 'functions', plugins_url( 'assets/functions.js', TS_FILE ), array('jquery'));
    wp_enqueue_script('functions');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ts_scripts' );
```

But I am not getting any alerts when I load the page. There are no error messages in my console.

Help?!

Comment: You say "at the top of the file".  **Which file** is your `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', ...` in?

Comment: In the plugin name file, basically the main one, so `wp-content/plugins/[plugin]/[plugin].php <-`